# Disallowed types file

Tags: codeigniter

It's easy to set the allowed file in code igniter when we want to upload file if the amount is less. But if there are almost extension file I want to set as allowed types of file that can be uploade except file extension of .exe, how the easiest way to set the code ? besides I have to type all of type code in allowed_types configuration. ..

Comment: There is no other way. You have to point all allowed extensions in array because for PHP parser it is just array of strings that is checked against uploaded file. There is no inbuilt PHP function that recognise all possible extensions. Way more because one can name file and extension what ever he/shw wants.

Comment: But I have read this web page http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/codeigniter-file-upload-setting-disallowed-file-types/ .....

Comment: And than? Have you finished? Btw. Concept of stackoverflow q&a can be learnt in [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Read it and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: it doesn't work when I try to follow that instructions. Thank you for your suggestion. I have try to type all kind of allowed extensions for upload the file. But when I try to upload .dwg extension, it doesn't work again. So I decided to find another way as I write in my first question. ..

Comment: You should post code that you have changed/tried so anybody could inspect and try to help. Also, don't forget to include actual controller code too.

Comment: Ok, this some of my controller for define .dwg as allowed types     $config['upload_path'] = $direktori . '/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'dwg';
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            
in mimes.php I include this code too    'dwg' =>  array('application/acad', 'application/x-acad','application/autocad_dwg', 'image/x-dwg', 'application/dwg', 'application/x-dwg', 'application/x-autocad', 'image/vnd.dwg', 'drawing/dwg')

Comment: It's unreadable. Please edit your question an wrap code with code tags. Again, check the atricle how full scaled question should look like.